# Change color of menu toggle in ionic2

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am developing an app in ionic2. I would like to change the `background-color` of the `menuToggle` to creme/white color and change the color of the three lines to black. The button code is given below:

```
<ion-col col-2>
    <button ion-button menuToggle
        small *ngIf="Buttonclicked"                
        (click)="editdata(item)"><ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-col>
```

Please guide in this regard.

Comment: don't put ionic code as we cannot test it, put your final HTML/CSS code

Comment: I build the app using ionic cli and then test the apk. I don't get to see html/css code.

Comment: i understand, but when viewing the application you can inspect the html/css  you get and put it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the color of an item you have to add the `color` directive:

```
<button ion-button menuToggle small color="white" *ngIf="Buttonclicked"(click)="editdata(item)">
  <ion-icon name="menu" color="black"></ion-icon>
</button>
```